# How to list/manipulate document bookmarks from within a Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I plan to develop an extension for Visual Studio that manipulates the document bookmarks. Basically, I want to be able to list the existing bookmarks, to create new ones and to remove any of the existing ones, for the whole solution.

The only place where I have found bookmark manipulation capabilities is [the TextSelection interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.textselection.aspx): it has `ClearBookmark`, `SetBookmark`, `PreviousBookmark` and `NextBookmark` methods; but these don't seem to be what I need, as they work for individual text selections only.

So, is there any other (solution wide) way to manipulate document bookmarks from within a Visual Studio extension? Or am I missing something and these existing methods actually provide the functionality that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bookmark information stored in .suo file. So you could read the .suo file with [IVsPersistSolutionOpts Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionopts.aspx).

It contains ReadUserOptions(IStream, String), SaveUserOptions(IVsSolutionPersistence) and WriteUserOptions(IStream, String) methods. You could use them to manage the bookmarks in your solution.

Comment: Thank you! I see that data in .suo files is read as key/value pairs, do you know which keys are involved in bookmarks management?

Comment: You could use some third part tools, such as Structured Storage Viewer(http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html), to check the detailed bookmarks information

Answer (score 1):

The following article provide a complete sample which could list and manage all bookmarks by creating a Bookmark class that represents a bookmark and a BookmarkManager class that keeps a dictionary (bookmark number is the key and the object of the Bookmark class is the value) of all bookmarks which are accessible through the public property Bookmarks

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61915/Numbered-Bookmarks-Visual-Studio-Extension-VSX

Comment: Thank you! That project, together with similar ones like [VSBookmarks by SergeyVinyar](https://github.com/SergeyVinyar/VSBookmarks), are about creating a completely new bookmarks engine. Rather, I was interested in managing the bookmarks engine that is built-in in Visual Studio.